# Send undefined datas to firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I'm working on an angular/firebase project, i'm having issues with optionals form fields, if one of these fields is empty, the form can't be sent, i searched about this and none of the solutions i found worked.

I get this error when i send a form with an empty field :

FirebaseError: Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined

I define my database settings in environment.ts file but i can't set the database to accepet empty fields here. Also I define the object to send in models.ts , i tried using any or undefined but it doesn't help.

Any tips to get this working ?
Thanks

Comment: do you tried this https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Settings#optional-ignoreundefinedproperties ?

Comment: So you just add this in environment.ts?

Comment: const db = firestore.firestore();
db.settings({ ignoreUndefinedProperties: true })

Comment: Well i tried to put this, i get no errors on compile but the problem is still here